# How to redirect Chargify hosted page to different URL

Tags: javascript, chargify

I have chargify hosted page but i would like to redirect it to different url as chargify have limited customization allowed on their public hosted pages, i have tried following code to redirect by putting into custom javascript area but it didn't work.

```
 window.onload = function() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                window.location = "https://reference.chargify.com/v1/subscriptions/create-subscription";
            }, 100);
        };
```

Looking forward to solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it needs to be window.location.href (not just window.location).  It worked for me with that addition.

This answer suggests that window.location.replace is preferable [How do I redirect to another webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-do-i-redirect-to-another-webpage)